# MediaWiki categories not updating automatically

Tags: mediawiki

I have a `MediaWiki` instance running on a Linux server that does not seem to automatically update its categories whenever a page edit is submitted.

I have never seen this on any other wikis I've worked with, so I'm wondering if there's some script that's not configured correctly.

Periodically running the `rebuildAll.php` or `refreshLinks.php` script isn't really viable when we have hundreds of edits happening per hour and need the categories to be populated instantaneously.

Running `rebuildAll.php` seems to take hours anyway.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's [$wgJobRunRate](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgJobRunRate) set to? Try running [maintenance/runJobs.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RunJobs.php).

It can sometimes take a while (minutes perhaps) for a page to appear in a category, but for most wikis it shouldn't be more than that.

Comment: runJobs.php cleared the queue which had built up.  Worked brilliantly.  Much appreciated!