# MediaWiki links not updating automatically, not solved by job queue

Tags: php, sqlite, mediawiki

I installed MediaWiki from the docker official container (https://hub.docker.com/_/mediawiki/) in a Google Cloud VM running Debian. All appears to be working fine, except that the category links are not updating (i.e., when I add or change categories or some pages' categories, these changes are not recognized by the indexes of pages within categories). If I run `refreshLinks.php`, all is updated fine.

I read in other posts that a possible reason could be the job queue ([MediaWiki categories not updating automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778490/mediawiki-categories-not-updating-automatically), https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:T9bp2ot4rm6lkula, https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Errors_and_symptoms#Category_pages,_Special:Whatlinkshere_and_file_usage_aren't_being_updated). So I changed `$wgJobRunRate` to 10, set `$wgRunJobsAsync` to false, and ran `runJobs.php`, but it did not change the behaviour. If I make changes to the pages' categories, the `showJobs.php` will say that I have 0 jobs in queue, but the categories would be wrong. I run `refreshLinks.php`, and the categories are fixed.

Used versions are: Mediawiki 1.31.0; PHP 7.2.8; SQLite 3.20.1; ICU 57.1.

I appreciate your help to get the usual behavior of links are automatically updating, so I don't have to keep running `refreshLinks.php`.

EDIT: Tested in a new VM, and in localhost, the issue reproduces. Tried setting `$wgJobRunRate` to 1, the issue persists.

EDIT2: Also asked on MediaWiki Support Desk. Error logs included there. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Uixgvt6t7upb1cc6

EDIT3: I did another install using the same mediawiki docker image, but now with a MariaDB container as database, and the categories and links are properly updating. So I think this is an issue when using SQLite.

Comment: Same here, I think this is a bug in mediawiki and needs reporting

Comment: I reported on Mediawiki phabricator, https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/project/view/3094/, but nobody responds yet. I tested on master branch and it does not work either (with SQLite). However the other two docker images (1.30.0, and 1.27) work well.